# How to suspend a thread until the connection is absent?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose I have a method that execute a web scraping for populate a combobox when the program start. The scenario is that the user start the software but there is no connection, so no data will be inserted in the combobox. I'm trying to execute that method in a while until the `connectionStatus` variable value change, a little example:

```
Thread connThread;
bool connectionStatus = false;

try
{
    connThread = new Thread(x =>
    {
        while (!connectionStatus)
        {
            if(connectionStatus) break;
            GetDataFromWeb(); 
        }
    });

    connThread.Start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{ 
    //There is no connection
    connectionStatus  = false;         
    connThread. //There is no SleepMethod ??
}
```

I need to display the application but in the mainwhile I need to suspend for a certain second the thread `connThread`, the problem's that I can't find any `Sleep` method, why?

Comment: Sleep is a static method, not an instance method.

Comment: What version of .Net framework does your project targets ? Btw this technique is called 'polling'

Comment: i have  the 4.6.1

Comment: Then you *don't* need threads or polling, you need to use `async/await`. This way you won't have to block any thread. HttpClient's methods are all asynchronous already. How is `connectionStatus` set?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Thread.Sleep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx). It is a static method of the `Thread` class.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleeps for 1 second
```

Calling this suspends the calling thread, so if you want to sleep inside your thread, put the try/catch inside the thread and call `Thread.Sleep` there.

For example, how I would do it:

```
var connThread = new Thread(x =>
{
    while(true) {
        try {
            GetDataFromWeb();
            break;
        } catch {
            // sleep for 1 second
            // and then try again
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
});

connThread.Start();
```

Also, be careful when adding items to the ComboBox, because all UI stuff must be done on the UI thread. In WPF, you can call `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()` to invoke the UI thread.

Comment: "Suspends the current thread..." - isn't that going to sleep the wrong thread?

Comment: I just added that to the answer. :D Will put code example also.